# Javascript method firing twice when using turbolink 5.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, turbolinks

Issue:

I have an E-commerce application built on Spree 3.7 and Rails 5.2, Right now I am facing turbolink(version 5.2.0) issue in which I have implemented javascript for adding items to the cart but js method firing twice and a similar item is being added into cart twice.

I have included following js in head tag-

```
<script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'spree/frontend/all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</script>
```

I have tried 'data-turbolinks-track': 'true/false' but my issue solved when removed

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`.

I read about turbolink from 'https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolink'. According to me turbolink is loading javascript method twice.

Any suggestions on how it can be solved?

After comment here is my application.js file

```
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require cable
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/sortable

//= require wishlist
//= require product
//= require cart
```

Comment: Can you show us your `application.js`? If you have `require_tree` in that file and your `spree` folder is within the same JS folder, then it's likely including your JS file in `application.js`

Comment: Is this happening in production, or on localhost?

Comment: @VeridianDynamics added js file in question

Comment: @NMPennypacker its in local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I was able to solve the issue, according to Turbolink our javascript should be wrapped in

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () { ... }
```

Our spree functions like addToCartForm etc. works on `$( document ).ready()`

So I have overridden those functions and wrapped in `turbolinks:load`, now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, you probably have two versions of compiled assets locally. Try running `rake assets:clobber` to clear out the additional assets.

Comment: Hey, it's not the case because sometimes it works as expected